# Parsing Python Script using AJAX request and showing data on same page in Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am trying to process a Python script using an AJAX Request. I am rendering my webpage on Flask. My solution was working on my local machine when I was not using Flask but I have started facing problems since I ported to Flask for deploying on Azure.

My goal is to pass "country" and "rate" from the form on my home.html page to the "script.py" file. The "script.py" utilizes these variables and prints out a static HTML response which will then should be updated in the "result" div tag of my HTML page.

Here is my Flask application.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My AJAX Request:

```
function python_process() {

    var rate = $('input[name=rate]').val();
    var country = $('select[name=country]').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: "/static/script.py",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "rate" : rate, 
            "country": country
            },

        success: function(data){
                    var result = $('<div>').append(data);
                    $('#result').html(result);
                },
        error:  function(){
                    console.log('in error');
                }
        });
};
```

Things I have tried:

1. Tried to make my script.py file a Flask method of its own, but the script is too large and always gives me a server error when I try that.
2. Tried console printing the "data" variable in the AJAX success call, but the default console log always shows "in error".

Comment: you can't do it this way. Url `/static/script.py` is directed to flask and flask try to send its content as normal file (ie. image, .css, etc). It will not exceute it. You have to send requests to some function in flask and flask has to execute it. And flask has to its result to client like any other template.

Comment: you may try to run `script.py` in flask using module `subprocess` and catch output.

Comment: @furas Where would I call subprocess in this case? And also that won't allow me to pass any variables from my HTML form to script.py

Comment: you would have to create function in Flask with ie. `@app.route('/scipt')` and inside this function run `subprocess`. And AJAX will run url `/script`. It is normal flask function so it can get arguments from AJAX. And `subprocess` can run `"script.py arg1 arg2 arg3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `subprocess` to run script in flask and catch output.

```
import subprocess

@app.route("/script", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    rate = request.form.get('rate', '')
    country = request.form.get('country', '')

    output = subprocess.check_output('python script.py {} {}'.format(rate, country), shell=True)

    return output
```

and AJAX would have to use url `/script`.

---

Minimal working example.

main.py (`flask` + `template` in one file)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, render_template_string
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- can't be `slim` version because it has not `$.ajax` -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Rate: <input type="text" name="rate"/><br/>
Country: <select name="country"/><option>France</option><option>Germany</option></select><br/>
<button>OK</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>$(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {

        var rate = $('input[name=rate]').val();
        var country = $('select[name=country]').val();

        // alert('rate: "' + rate + '" | country: "' + country + '"');

        $.post({
            url: "/script",
            data: {
                "rate" : rate, 
                "country": country
            },
            success: function(data){
                var result = $('<div>').append(data);
                $('#result').html(result);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('in error');
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>''')

@app.route("/script", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def script():
    rate = request.form.get('rate')
    country = request.form.get('country')

    print('[form] rate: "{}" | country: "{}"'.format(rate, country))

    # I use `""` to send empty string as argument
    output = subprocess.check_output('python3 script.py "{}" "{}"'.format(rate, country), shell=True)

    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import sys

rate = '?'
country = '?'

# send on screen instead of sending to flask
sys.stderr.write( '[sys.argv] {}\n'.format(str(sys.argv)) )

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    rate = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    country = sys.argv[2]

print('[script.py] rate: "{}" | country: "{}"'.format(rate, country))
```

Comment: Tried this out, thanks but the console shows me the following error - 

POST http://<url>/script 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: sorry, it should be [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `call_output`. And `request.form` instead of `request.post`. If script is not set as executable then you may need `python script.py` in check_output. BTW: if you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe then it should show you more information about problem.

Comment: I added minimal working example which i used to test it.

Comment: Have been testing this out, but problem seems to be in the form request variables transferring to the script. I get the output - "[script.py] rate: "None" | country: "None"", indicating these request form get variables are not getting assigned correctly. My earlier script was using CGI modules which I replaced with your sys modules in my script

Comment: if you get `None` then it was executed as `script.py None None` and it means it couldn't get values from `request.form` - BTW: I aready mentioned it - in first version I had `request.post` but it has to be `request.form`

Comment: BTW: you can add `print(request.form)` to check if you get values from AJAX. You can use `print()` in other places to check what is in variables.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the issue was in a different part of my script file!